# How to unlock content in Magic Origins

Tags: magic-duels

Magic Origins has a *story mode* where you play as a planeswalker and earn some gold.

I played through the whole first story (all battles, all skill matches) and the other planeswalkers are still locked.

**What do I need to do to access the other four?**

I bought the packs as suggested, I replayed that last guy Iora game, I logged in and off. If there was some hint, I missed it.
I saw people on the Internet lament about the game crashing while playing as Chandra, so I'm pretty sure it's not something that would be unlocked later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you bought the packs you need to continue to the deck manager to create a custom deck. With that deck you need to complete a "Battle" game, it doesn't matter if solo or versus.

After that, the other 4 stories are unlocked.

Sadly there's no quest log, so you have to pay attention to what the annoying tutorial says.

Comment: I closed the PC without quitting Magic Origins (I tabbed out and gort lost doing other things) so I guess I missed that tutorial speech.